# Writing to 'Problems' table or 'Console' from Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a plug-in and as part of the functionality of the plug-in, I need to write something into the 'Problems' table or 'Console'.

I'm trying to make it quite similar to how Eclipse shows errors/warnings when it builds.

I have the Error Code, Error Message and the Line number. I have successfully created the logic behind this on an SWT application using a table. However, I now need to create a plug-in. So far, I am trying ways to display it on the 'Problems' table of Eclipse.

In a desperate attempt, I tried writing to the console with

```
System.out.println
System.console().writer().println(),
```

but it didn't work. I also tried using

```
StatusManager ab;
IStatus status = new Status(Status.ERROR, "HELLO", "HELLO!");
ab.handle(status, 0);
```

But it seems I need to initialize ab, but I can't do that with

```
StatusManager ab = new StatusManager();
```

I also tried

```
logger.info("Info!");
logger.severe("Error!");
logger.warning("Warning!");
```

But they do not work either.

```
Plugin ab;
ab.getLog().log(new Status(Status.INFO,"Hello", "hehe"));
```

Doesn't work either cause I need to initialize ab, which

```
Plugin ab = new Plugin();
```

I really need a bit of help to push me to the right direction on how to do this.

P.S: The console or the problems table I'm mentioning is the actual Eclipse one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problems views shows `IMarker` objects with a type of Problem.

Marker objects are always associated with an `IResource` object (or one of its derived interfaces such as `IFile` and `IFolder`).

You create a marker with something like:

```
IFile file = .... get file to mark 

IMarker marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);

marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line number);
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "error message");
marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
```

You can use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` extension point to define your own marker type which will help you distinguish your markers from other plug-in's markers.

Comment: There is always workspace root to use when no file is available: `IResource  root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()`

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly! Your answer combined with @Basilevs worked like a charm. Thank you very much! Finally!

Comment: Just a little follow-up question @greg-449, with regards to `file.createMarker(IMarker.PROBLEM);`, in the problem's table it shows the type is 'Problem', can I change this to a custom string such as 'Syntax Check'?. I tried changing it but the marker isn't getting created if I change `IMarker.Problem`.

Comment: Use the `org.eclipse.core.resources.markers` extension point to create a custom marker type that 'extends' the problem type (`org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker`). See the example in the extension point documentation.